# Software Cannot Initialize

Tags: .net, testing, startup, boot

I've encountered a problem when loading software(to be more specific, it is an industrial database viewer). However, the software can't seem to boot up. I have enclosed the error below which seems like a system language problem.

**.NET Runtime**

```
Exception Information:TypeinitializationException:System.Runtime.InteropService.COMEception 
 Congnex.SISD.CommonStrings.StringsBase..cctor()


Exception Information:System.TypeinitializationException
 Cognex.SISD CommonStrings.StringsBase.add_LanguageChanged(System.EventHandler)
 Cognex.SISD.CommonStrings.Globalizer..ctor(System.ComponentModel.IContainer)
 Cognex.SISD CommonForms.AboutForm.InitializeComponent()
 Cognex.SISD.CommonForms.AboutForm..ctor（Boolean）
 Cognex.SISD PQA.MainForm.Main（System.String[]）
```

**Execution Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework, Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

**System Info**
OS: Windows 10 Pro (Traditional Chinese)

Any suggestion on the problem or attempts for a solution would be extremely thankful.

We've tried re-installing another version of the software and installing Cpp redistributable. On the other hand, we also copy the file and REG from the working computer to the non-functioning computer
to overwrite. But none of them work.

Comment: TypeinitializationException usually has an InnerException. Basically, you should see if you can get a fuller stack trace.

Comment: TypeinitializationException:System.Runtime.InteropService.COMEception  at  Congnex.SISD.CommonStrings.StringsBase..cctor()

Comment: Please put all that information in the *question* rather than in comments - ideally with anything else in there (such as the exception message).

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I've included the exception and order in the main problem! Can you spot where is the main issue?

Comment: No, I'm afraid there still really isn't enough information. I suggest you get in touch with the supplier of the software.